# How can I fix this error with plotweb2 in bipartite package?

Tags: r

I try to build a tritrophic network using plotweb2 in bipartite. 
I have 2 diferent quantitative adjacency matrix (one linking level 1 with 2 and another linking level 2 with 3).

The problem become when I try to use the function plotweb2. I obtain this error:

> Error in dummy[i] <- dummy[i] - lowfreq[which(names(lowfreq) == names(dummy[i]))] : 
>     replacement has length zero

What is the problem?? any suggestions to fix it?

My code is:

```
library(bipartite)

net1<-read.delim("net1.txt", row.names=1) net2<-read.delim("net2.txt", row.names=1)

plotweb2(net1,net2)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

plotweb2 uses matrices instead of data frames. Try converting both objects to matrices first

```
    library(bipartite)
    net1<-read.delim("net1.txt", row.names=1) net2<-read.delim("net2.txt", row.names=1)

    net1 <- as.matrix(net1)
    net2 <- as.matrix(net2)

    plotweb2(net1,net2)
```